# SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers() returns no recognizers

Tags: c#, kinect, speech-recognition, kinect-sdk

I'm trying to run some speech recognition code that I have up and going on my desktop on my laptop.

After debugging the code a bit, it seems that on my laptop it's not seeing any speech recognition engines. I can see SR_MS_en-US_Kinect_11.0 is installed and is visible in my registry, but when I run InstalledRecognizers() it returns nothing. Any idea how to get these reco engines visible in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Are you *sure* you've installed the server SR engines?  It's a separate installation.  The control panel won't show server SR engines, and the Microsoft.Speech namespace won't work unless the server SR engines are installed.